# Is firebase for android thread safe?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This question is super obvious but there isn't a straight answer on google documentation and i'm having trouble to test it

Let me describe the scenario:

1- I've a database which just allows authenticated users to query
2- I'm authenticate the users bymyself but i user firebase to assign a token to them
3- while firebase assigns a token to the user other thread may start querying

Code:

```
//do my stuff to authenticate
//....
//....
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCustomToken(token);
 DatabaseReference fire = ((App) getApplication()).getFirebase();
fire.child("actions").orderByChild("added").startAt(from).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){/*do my stuff*/});
```

So I will always be querying ONLY AFTER calling `signInWithCustomToken`, but I'm not waiting for its result before start querying it... does firebase synchronize it internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[signInWithCustomToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signInWithCustomToken(java.lang.String)) is asynchronous and returns a Task that indicates when it's complete.  Your code needs to wait on that task to complete before performing queries that require authentication.  What you've written right now won't work the way you expect, because the authentication will not have completed before the query is executed.

The issue here isn't threadsafety.  You just need to do asynchronous programming with Tasks correctly.

[Read about the Play Services tasks API.](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks)
[Learn more about using Tasks with Firebase.](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html)